# How to get around memory limits in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, clickhouse

I want to create a visualisation in Grafana that would show queries ran by users. So I wrote this script

```
WITH
  dates AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT event_date, if(initial_user == '', 'default', initial_user) as user, query, http_user_agent
    from system.query_log log
    where event_date >= today() - 30
      and type in ('QueryStart')
```

So, the problem is that sometimes I get NoData, because of memory limits. If I change 30 to 14 all is good. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: !  Your Grafana query might be trying to handle too much data at once.
Remember, write your Grafana queries efficiently. A sloppy query can waste memory and time.